# MongoDB, find field into array

Tags: mongodb, find

I have items like these in my collection

```
{
user: data,
somestuff: [somedata ...], 
terminals: [ {
   label: data,
   details: [{more content}, {}, ...]
   }]
}
```

I would use 'find' to extract "details" field for a specific terminal 'label'
I know that there is an easy way to get the "terminals" array by:

```
collection.find({_id: "..."}, {_id:0, terminals: 1})
```

Wich return

```
{ terminals: [ {
   label: data,
   details: [{more content}, {}, ...]
   }]
}
```

I tried

```
collection.find({ "terminals.label": data }, { _id: 0, "terminals.$.details": 1 })
```

As edirican has suggested
And it almost work, but it return the same structure than previously except that the terminals list contain only the labeled document

The result I expect is the details list, extracted from terminals

```
{ details: [{more content}, {}, ...] }
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: It's not clear what your looking for. Can you update your question with an example of the result you're expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use positional ($) projection.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/

```
collection.find({ "terminals.label": 2 }, { _id: 0, "terminals.$.details": 1 })
```